# how to set geom_rect() xmin and xmax with monthly dates so they touch but do not overlap?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made a plot of sea surface temperature anomaly data as a color gradient in the background using ggplot2. The goal is to be able to look for correlations between ENSO events and species density, size frequencies distributions, or biomass. The gradient is horizontal and based on the following dataset: [Nino 34 Data](https://origin.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/analysis_monitoring/ensostuff/detrend.nino34.ascii.txt).

Does anyone have any suggestions for making the gradient better so there are no overlapping dates? The data is monthly, and right now I am simply plotting 15 days before the date and 16 days after to leave no small blank spaces. However, this way produces overlap. The ribbon data is the same data but with a plot which I know is accurate (simply there to check that the color gradient is acting appropriately).

This image is what my code produces:

[image: Nino 34 plot]

I am rather new to R so any suggestions on the plot would be much appreciated. This is just the first step towards overlaying the other things I mentioned

Here is the code:

```
library(tidyverse)    
oni <- read_csv("nino34.csv")    

ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = oni, 
            aes(xmin= Date - 15, xmax = Date + 16, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = Anom), 
            position = "identity")+
  geom_ribbon(data = oni, aes(x= Date, ymin = 0, ymax = Anom)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y", date_breaks = "1 year") +
  labs(title = "Oceanic Nino Index (ONI)",
       subtitle = "Nino Region 3.4 (5N-5S,120-170W)",
       fill = "Anomoly Intensity",
       x = "Date",
       y = "Sea Surface Temperature Anomoly Gradient") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", mid = "white", midpoint = 0) +
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.background = element_rect(),
        legend.title = element_text(angle = 0, size = 16, face = "bold"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 22, face = "bold"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 16),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 45, size = 14, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1, 
                                   size = 14, face = "bold"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the lubridate package to set the `xmin`/`xmax` to the start and end of the month:

```
library(lubridate)

oni <- read.table("../Downloads/nino34.txt", header = T)

# Set start date as first day of month
oni$DateStart <- as.Date(ISOdate(oni$YR, oni$MON, 1))

# Set end date as last day of the start date's month
oni$DateEnd <- ceiling_date(oni$DateStart, "month")
```

And then we could plot as follows:

```
ggplot(oni) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin= DateStart, xmax = DateEnd, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = ANOM), 
            position = "identity")+
  geom_ribbon(aes(x= DateStart, ymin = 0, ymax = ANOM)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y", date_breaks = "1 year") +
  labs(title = "Oceanic Nino Index (ONI)",
       subtitle = "Nino Region 3.4 (5N-5S,120-170W)",
       fill = "Anomoly Intensity",
       x = "Date",
       y = "Sea Surface Temperature Anomoly Gradient") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", mid = "white", midpoint = 0) +
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.background = element_rect(),
        legend.title = element_text(angle = 0, size = 16, face = "bold"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 22, face = "bold"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 16),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 45, size = 14, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1, 
                                   size = 14, face = "bold"))
```

[image]

Small note: the column names I got from the data differ slightly from your code, and I think it is spelled 'anomaly' instead of 'anomoly'.