# R - Filled area using geom_rect or annotate rect, returning errors

Tags: r, date, shapes, annotate, geom

I'm trying to create a colored/shaded horizontal band across my graph in RStudio. I want the filled band between 60 and 100 on the y axis, the entire length of the x axis.

x axis is a date range
y axis is numerical

Here's my [Data set](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tWLlvfhkuhs7dZ1GnlDo9basgkzInX5y_BCT3OLPyOo/edit?usp=sharing)

I've tried a few different things, such as geom rect and annotate rect, and I think I know why I'm receiving the errors but I don't know how to work the code differently to make it work. I would prefer a filled area over the annotate, but at this point, whichever works is a good start.

You can probably tell, I'm an infant in R.

Here's my working code and resulting visual:

```
# load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)

# set theme
theme_set(
  theme_classic() +
    theme(legend.position = "right", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)))

# load data
heartrates_vis1 <- read_csv("/Documents/R/Casestudy_Bellabeat/cleaned_data/fitbit_hr_min_max_per_id_date_2.csv")

pal <- c(
  "2022484408" = "aquamarine",
  "2026352035" = "blue",
  "2347167796" = "blueviolet",
  "4020332650" = "chartreuse",
  "4388161847" = "coral",
  "4558609924" = "cornflowerblue",
  "5553957443" = "cyan",
  "5577150313" = "darkgoldenrod",
  "6117666160" = "cadetblue",
  "6775888955" = "burlywood4",
  "6962181067" = "chocolate1",
  "7007744171" = "darkgreen",
  "8792009665" = "firebrick",
  "8877689391" = "darkseagreen"
)

heartrates_vis1 %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = date, y = meanhr, color = factor(id))) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %d", date_breaks = "1 day") +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = pal) +
  labs(title = "bellabeat Case Study: Insights from FitBit Heart Rate Readings", 
       subtitle = "Daily Averages per Participant from April 12-May 12, 2016",
       caption = "\n Data source: Kaggle user - Möbius\n Link: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/arashnic/fitbit",
       color = "Session id",
       x = "HR Reading Date", 
       y = "Average of Daily Readings")
```

[image]

I tried to add (with and without 'mapping =':

```
+   geom_rect(mapping = aes(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = 60, ymax = 100, alpha = 1/5, fill = "aliceblue"))
```

And received the following error:
**Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only**

I then tried to add:

```
+
annotate("rect", xmin = "2016-04-11", xmax = "2016-05-13", ymin = 60, ymax = 100, alpha = .2, fill = "blue")
```

And again received the same error:
**Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only**

I'd like to get something like this gray area fill (my same dataset in Tableau):

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you need to convert `xmin` and `xmax` to Date using `as.Date()` function?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/62740672/786542 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/58970059/786542